# Dynamic Data Display: hide the axis lable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am a new gay on WPF and D3.

The value of X axis in my chart is not meaningful(just 1,2,3,....), so I want to hide the value, just keep the ticks.

How can I do this?

Tnx for anyone whose can help.

Comment: @Bizz Yeah I have tried to find a method, but I can not make it work.

Comment: I don't have an idea. But since you haven't found anything to disable the labels, you should probably find a way to override the axis label style or template.

Answer (score 0):

Know this has been up for a year but I stumbled across the question as I had the same problem. I was looking to remove the x axis as am just plotting Voltage vs time in real time and the time unit isn't important.

Anyway the solution turned out to be simple.

```
plotter.HorizontalAxis.Remove();
```

So my setup C# code behind the WPF now looks like this.

```
public graph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        _voltagePointCollection = new VoltagePointCollection();

        var ds = new EnumerableDataSource<VoltagePoint>(_voltagePointCollection);
        //ds.SetXMapping(x => dateAxis.ConvertToDouble(x.Date));
        ds.SetXMapping(x => x.tick);
        ds.SetYMapping(y => y.Voltage);            
        plotter.AddLineGraph(ds, Colors.Green, 2, "Volts"); 

        MaxVoltage = 1;
        MinVoltage = 0;
        BackgroundColor = Brushes.White;
        YRangeMin = 0;
        YRangeMax = 30;
        plotter.HorizontalAxis.Remove();
        plotter.LegendVisible = false;

    }
```

Hope this helps someone.